# Джейден Смит цитаты

Tags: python

проходил задание на сайте codewars.com про Джейдена Смитта

Jaden Smith, the son of Will Smith, is the star of films such as The Karate Kid (2010) and After Earth (2013). Jaden is also known for some of his philosophy that he delivers via Twitter. When writing on Twitter, he is known for almost always capitalizing every word. For simplicity, you'll have to capitalize each word, check out how contractions are expected to be in the example below.

Your task is to convert strings to how they would be written by Jaden Smith. The strings are actual quotes from Jaden Smith, but they are not capitalized in the same way he originally typed them.

Example:

Not Jaden-Cased: "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
Jaden-Cased:     "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"

написал вот такой код

```
def to_jaden_case(string):
    lst=[]
    x=string.split()
    for i in x:
        y=i.capitalize()
        lst.append(y)
        str="\""+(' '.join(lst))+"\""
    return print(str)
```

а сайт говорит что у меня что то не так.
что я сделал не так?

Comment: может к строке не надо добавлять кавычек?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция print возвращает None, а вы зачем-то пытаетесь возвращать print. Сделайте так.

```
return str
```

Comment: все верно! и еще кавычки были лишние

Answer (score 1):

а такой вариант не проще ли?

```
text = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"

res = ' '.join(map(lambda word: word.capitalize(), text.split()))

print(res)
```

P.S.

в вашем коде вы добавляете кавычки в начало и конец строки - этого не стоит делать, поскольку в исходной строке этого нет

P.P.S.

кроме того ваша функция возвращает `None` и выводит на экран. Для задачи требуется написать функцию, которая выводит на экран или все таки возвращает значение?